# ADFS Metadata not accessible from outside

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, metadata, adfs

I set an ADFS server (Windows Server 2012 R2) for a SSO Portal. I have only one server, with ADFS and ADDS.

When I call `https://localhost/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml` from the server I get the Metadata XML.

But when I try `https://[IP ADDRESS]/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml` I get and error saying the address is not accessible.

Port 443 is accessible. I've used Powershell to check it:

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 443 -ComputerName [IP ADDRESS]
```

Tried all suggestions on StackOverflow and nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

I was trying to access metadata using the server IP Address. I've set a binding for HTTPS with IP address and it worked well.

Comment: Hi how did you do this? I'm having an almost similar issue with ADFS on Server 2016. I cant only access the sign-on page via localhost/adfs. I created an A record DNS with the server's IP but it does not work

Comment: U need to go into the IIS/Sites/Default Web Site and then in Actions select Bindings. In there create a new binding for https with port 443, and use a self-signed certificate. Everything else leave blank and save it. Now it should be accessible from public.